# Java stack monitoring

Tags: java, stack, monitoring

I have a very small main program that just initializes two variables and operates on them. I'm busy with trying to figure out what the bytecode does by using javap.

I get things like this in the output:

```
public class Test2 {
  public Test2();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: iconst_1
       1: istore_1
       2: iconst_2
       3: istore_2
```

Now I would like to monitor the stack to see what is happening on there and see how it relates to the bytecode of this very small program. It is possible to monitor the stack with jstack but then you should have a pid, which isn't a problem itself. The problem is that the program is so small and finished so fast that even thinking of launching jstack is impossible. So how can I monitor an application's stack that finishes quite fast. Can I record the stack or something and monitor it afterwards or is the thing that I'm trying to do just not possible?

Comment: By "monitoring", what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Viewing the local variables of the current function and how they change per statement executed.

Comment: Perhaps stepping through the code in a debugger would do what you need?

Comment: Not really. I'm trying out some compound bitwise operators, a step is too big to monitor the granularity I want.